# Orchestration and EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I want to run multiple  spark jobs in emr cluster with these jobs having some dependency among each other and once everything is complete the last sstep should trigger a lambda which will start another emr cluster with a bunch of spark jobs. Then once the last job in this 2nd emr cluster completes, I need to start another emr cluster(again using  a different lambda) with bunch of spark jobs. Once all the process are complete I ll send a notification using SNS. can this level of orchestration be achieved using step fucntion?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, step function will be able to do the tasks you have outlined. At high level you will need the following tasks in the Step Function to represent the job and its execution.

- EMR createCluster.sync (Job Flow id as o/p)
- EMR addStep | addStep.sync (Job Flow Id as input, job step id as op)
- Lambda Invoke (Job step Id(s) as input)
- Wait task (For polling the Job steps)
- setClusterTerminationProtection (Job Flow Id as input)
- terminateCluster.sync(Job Flow Id as input)
- SNS Publish Task
  (Message)